# How can I use js to force a browser window to go to a specific anchor tag should that anchor tag form part of the url?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I need to use js to force the browser to go to the anchor tag #showcase in the home page of mysite.com:

```
mysite.com/#showcase
```

If someone enters the url `mysite.com` though, I want the browser to load the page normally.

This should be a fairly simple if/else script surely, but having trouble finding a good cross-browser script that works.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following code

```
window.location.replace("#showcase")
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Much appreciated. I've tried using your script but it didn't work. The site in question is a video portfolio Wordpress site that has to load an intro video and and sections of video portfolio so a lot of visual assets to load first. I tried accessing my own personal site by appending #anchortag to the URL and it worked fine so there's a Wordpress page loading issue going on.

Answer (score 0):

This has the if statement you're looking for:

```
element = document.querySelector('#element-id')
if (location.hash == '#showcase') element.scrollIntoView()
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Much appreciated. I've tried using this script but it didn't work. The site in question is a video portfolio Wordpress site that has to load an intro video and and sections of video portfolio so a lot of visual assets to load first. I tried accessing my own personal site by appending #anchortag to the URL and it worked fine so there's a Wordpress page loading issue going on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to use any JavaScript for this.

You have to place your anchor tag in your home page like this:

```
<a href="#" id="showcase">showcase</a>
```

Make sure that the id is the same as your url parameter. In the example above, the id is equal to the url you want.

This will work for any element you have, just make the id the same as in the url.

I made a simple codesandbox, here is the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/url-anchor-tag-c3tw5?file=/index.html